# Javascript - Food totals array crashing

Tags: javascript, loops, iteration, nested-loops

I have an JS object of food totals

```
foodData: [
    { biscuits: 2, cola:2, sandwiches:0, cake:0 },
    { biscuits: 2, cola:2, sandwiches:0, cake:0 },
    { biscuits: 2, cola:0, sandwiches:0, cake:0 },
    {biscuits: 2, cola:0, sandwiches:0, cake:0 },
    {biscuits: 2, cola:0, sandwiches:0, cake:0 },
    {biscuits: 2, cola:0, sandwiches:4, cake:0 },
    {biscuits: 0, cola:0, sandwiches:0, cake:4 }
],
```

What I am trying to do is delete the number of user pledged "Bad foods" per day. Ultimately to calculate calories saved.

The items should be removed from the first index and then in order, so if they need to delete 2 bits of food, it will remove a biscuit if possible, then cola, then a sandwich, and then a cake.

They can remove 5 bits of food so it may iterate around taking 1 off every food stuff and then back to biscuits. This is what the count should do

The code below works but gets stuck when looping around (anything over 3 items). I suspect it is the if statements or possibly the internal count. Any suggestion in to how this stop getting stuck in a constant loop. I suppose breaking out of the if statement when the condition is met would help.

```
var array_of_functions = [this.totalMonday, this.totalTuesday, this.totalWednesday, this.totalThursday, this.totalThursday,  this.totalFriday, this.totalSaturday, this.totalSunday];

for (i = 0; i < array_of_functions.length; i++) {

  if (array_of_functions[i] > 0) {

    count = 0;
    do {


      if (this.foodData[i]['biscuits'] > 0 && count < this.noRemovedFoods) {
        this.foodData[i]['biscuits']--;
        ++count;
      }

      if (this.foodData[i]['cola'] > 0 && count < this.noRemovedFoods) {
        this.foodData[i]['cola']--;
        ++count;
      }

      if (this.drinksData[i]['sandwiches'] > 0 && count < this.noRemovedFoods) {
        this.drinksData[i]['sandwiches']--;
        ++count;
      }
      if (this.foodData[i]['cake'] > 0 && count < this.noRemovedFoods) {
        this.dataData[i]['cake']--;
        ++count;
      }
    } while (count < this.noRemovedFoods)

  }

}
```

Comment: Why is Friday used twice?

Comment: sorry mistake - been removed.

Comment: Don't modify the code. It invalidates existing answers.

Comment: the code is not how it should be

Comment: So? If your code were completely correct, then what use is the question? Modifying the code confuses future readers, because your code doesn't match with your question.

Comment: jsfiddle please. Otherwise it's not quite clear where the problem could be. E.g. from above code it seems that ```this.drinksData``` does not even exist.

Comment: @newBee neither does `this.dataData`.

Comment: I still think there's too much confusion. First of all, there's not all code present, there are(were) trivial errors in the code, and the question also seems too broad(no specific location where the code is getting stuck, etc).

Answer (score 0):

It would have been good if you have provided more code or with proper meaningful code(e.g I don't know what drinksData is). I have assumed your code inside do-while loop looks something like this:

```
if (this.foodData[i]['biscuits'] > 0 && count < this.noRemovedFoods) {
  this.foodData[i]['biscuits']--;
  ++count;
}

if (this.foodData[i]['cola'] > 0 && count < this.noRemovedFoods) {
  this.foodData[i]['cola']--;
  ++count;
}

if (this.foodData[i]['sandwiches'] > 0 && count < this.noRemovedFoods) {
  this.foodData[i]['sandwiches']--;
  ++count;
}

if (this.foodData[i]['cake'] > 0 && count < this.noRemovedFoods) {
  this.foodData[i]['cake']--;
  ++count;
}
```

In this case, you will get stuck in an infinite loop. The problem is in your do-while loop condition. There will be case when count will not get incremented if all foodData items bit gets to zero and you will get stuck in an infinite loop because of not meeting the condition `count < this.noRemovedFoods`.

One thing you can do is to break out of do-while loop if all food items bit gets to zero. If I consider your code as I understood, rewriting above code to break do-while loop may look like this:

```
do {
  if (this.foodData[i]['biscuits'] > 0 && count < this.noRemovedFoods) {
    this.foodData[i]['biscuits']--;
    ++count;
  }

  if (this.foodData[i]['cola'] > 0 && count < this.noRemovedFoods) {
    this.foodData[i]['cola']--;
    ++count;
  }

  if (this.foodData[i]['sandwiches'] > 0 && count < this.noRemovedFoods) {
    this.foodData[i]['sandwiches']--;
    ++count;
  }

  if (this.foodData[i]['cake'] > 0 && count < this.noRemovedFoods) {
    this.foodData[i]['cake']--;
    ++count;
  }

  if(this.foodData[i]['biscuits'] == 0 && this.foodData[i]['cola'] == 0 && this.foodData[i]['sandwiches'] == 0 && this.foodData[i]['cake'] == 0) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Just check if all food items bit has become zero to break out of the do-while loop.